# $batch requests - do they provide a client performance speedup compared to requests executed one by one

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

The $batch requests in xrm are supposed to be used for number of operations that either succeed or fail as a group.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api

I.E. instead of

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/tasks
{ ...payload for task1.. }
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/tasks
{ ...payload for task2.. }
```

You create request

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/$batch
{ .... shared payload ... }
```

Now my question is are they supposed to provide performance speedup for the client loading as well ? I.E. when I'll user $batch is the overall client performance supposed to be better ?

*EDIT*

Test snippet  I've used:

```
syncTest = function() {
  var now = Date.now();
  var count = 0;
  var done = function() {
    count++;
    if (count === 2) {
      console.log("Sync: " + (Date.now() - now) + " ms");
    }
  };

  $.ajax({method:"GET",url:"/api/data/v9.0/contacts(53c4918e-5367-e911-a83b-000d3a31329f)", success: function() { done(); }});
  $.ajax({method:"GET",url:"/api/data/v9.0/contacts(50b297c5-4867-e911-a843-000d3a3130ea)", success: function() { done(); }});
};

asyncTest = function() {
  var now = Date.now();
  var done = function() {
    console.log("Async: " + (Date.now() - now) + " ms");
  };

  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_123456',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Odata-MaxVersion': '4.0',
    'Odata-Version': '4.0'
  };

  var data = [];
  data.push('--batch_123456');
  data.push("Content-Type: application/http");
  data.push("Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary");
  data.push('');
  data.push('GET /api/data/v9.0/contacts(53c4918e-5367-e911-a83b-000d3a31329f) HTTP/1.1');
  data.push('Content-Type:application/json;type=entry');
  data.push('');
  data.push('{}');

  data.push('--batch_123456');  
  data.push("Content-Type: application/http");
  data.push("Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary");
  data.push('');
  data.push('GET /api/data/v9.0/contacts(50b297c5-4867-e911-a843-000d3a3130ea) HTTP/1.1');
  data.push('Content-Type:application/json;type=entry');
  data.push('');
  data.push('{}');  
  data.push('--batch_123456');
  var payload = data.join('\r\n');

  $.ajax({method:"POST",url:"/api/data/v9.0/$batch", data:payload, headers: headers, success: function() { done(); }});
};
```

Test method - flush browser cache execute snippet; times (average for five retries):

```
$batch                 - 242ms per combined request (average for 5x)
one by one in parallel - 195ms per combined request (average for 5x)
```

So it seems $batch is actually adding some overhead.

Comment: My guess is that because `$batch` is transactional, that is the cause of the overhead

Answer (score 0):

The Web API batch can accept 100 records, which may provide improved performance compared to one by one in parallel. This would be primarily due to reducing the number of communications between client and server, which can be a performance issue in high latency environments. As noted below its not specifically designed to cater for this scenario however, its primarily to achieve transactional behaviour.

[Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api) operations using the Web API are somewhat similar to the [ExecuteTransactionRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/use-executetransaction) and [ExecuteMultipleRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/execute-multiple-requests) of the Organization Service.

### `Batch`

- Provide a way to bundle a number of operations that either succeed or fail as a group.
- Transactional behaviour: Yes.
- Max batch size: 100.

#### `ExecuteTransactionRequest`

- Execute multiple operations in a single transaction with the ability to roll back all data changes should any one operation fail.
- Transactional behaviour: Yes.
- Max batch size: two or more (probably 1000 if it matches `ExecuteMultipleRequest`).

#### `ExecuteMultipleRequest`

- Improve performance where internet latency can be the [largest limiting factor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-executemultiple-improve-performance-bulk-data-load).
- Transactional behaviour: No.
- Max batch size: 1000, two concurrent calls.

Answer (score 0):

For your requests, since they are running async, both requests will be sent to the server, and will be processed asynchronously vs, the batch, which will process them one at a time.  So I would imagine that total execution time would be less for the two async, vs the one async, but because of server processing, not client side issues.  You could change your calls to by sync instead and see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Batch Request will save Round Trip times. That the Main Performance Advantage. Sending out 2x Requests sequentially, is way slower then sending out only 1 Request. As stated by Daryl, your 2 Request are send out Async (which more or less means parallel). That the reason why you see a difference. So you basically compare Parallel Processing with Single Threading.